# Getting specific value from specific key of Document inside document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document something like this

```
{ "_id": { "$oid" : "51776bca40bcc60038000001" }, 
"username": "domi55", 
"Password": "test", 
"Character": { "Job": "Warrior", 
               "Level": 1,
               "Skill": { "SkillID": "1001", 
                          "SkillName": "Blade Dance",
                          "LevelRequirment": 1 
                        }
              }
          }
}
```

How do I get the "Job" value and the "SkillName" value in C#?
I'm using MongoDB and MongoDB C# Driver

Comment: What have you tried? The docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-tutorial) cover this very well. You can use a `BsonDocument` or strongly typed objects.

Comment: I do using it, but still it can't get me the `"Job"` instead it give me the whole `"Character"` Document including its `"Skill"` Document

Comment: Edit your question to include what you've tried please.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourDoc);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", obj.Character.Job, obj.Character.Skill.SkillName);
```

or using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",obj["Character"]["Job"],obj["Character"]["Skill"]["SkillName"]);
```

Comment: so with out json.net, I couldn't get the value?

Comment: I need to ask, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourDoc)` giving me Error because it didn't accept `yourDoc` but accepting `string` data type

Comment: @Diom of course. You should read the doc from disk/network before passing to json parsers.

Comment: so `yourDoc` is actually not a Document but a string? so how I changed it to string?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use Json with MongoDb to access the data.  Check my comment on the question for a link to the relevant docs.